# Calculate the radius of convergence of the power series

Tags: analysis

Given the power series $\sum ^{\infty}_{j=0}\dfrac{x^{j}}{j+1}$
Using either the ratio or root test, how do I calculate the radius of convergence?

Comment: Your question is basically the answer - what does the ratio test give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ratio test: $$\frac{x^{j+1}}{j+2}\times \frac{j+1}{x^j } = x\frac{j+1}{j+2} \rightarrow x$$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$. Thus $|x|<1$.